# validation value having two possible types

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

How to validate request value when it should be string or array both valid?

```
'val' => 'bail|required|string'
'val' => 'bail|required|array'
```

What would be the the validation expression?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to achieve it using the validation rules out of the box. You will need to use [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) to achieve this:

In `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot` method, add in

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('string_or_array', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        return is_string($value) || is_array($value);
    });
}
```

Then you can start using it:

```
'val' => 'bail|required|string_or_array'
```

Optionally you can set the custom validation error messages, or using a custom validation class to achieve it. Check out the doc link above for more information.

Comment: Why 4 params in the function if only using 1 param (`$value`)?

Comment: @ericmp I'm listing all possible arguments. You can declare just two params `$attributes` and `$value` and use the `$value` parameter only.

Answer (score 5):

The solution provided by @lionel-chan is most elegant way but you can also do it by checking type of the variable in order to add the appropriate rule as:

```
$string_or_array_rule = is_array($inputs['val']) ? 'array' : 'string'

"val" => "bail|required|{$string_or_array_rule}"
```

Answer (score 2):

only changed @Krezo's answer to ternary operator

```
'val' => ['bail','required',function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
    (is_array($value) || is_string($value))?: $fail("Must be array or string");
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use closure

```
"val" => [function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
         if (!(is_array($value) || is_string($value))) $fail("$attribute must be array or string");
     }]
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to add details or explaination of your answer ? Specially why and how this can answer the question